# C#. Как изменить условие, чтобы строки брались из списка?

Tags: c#, linq, поиск

Нужно переделать условие таким образом, чтобы строки для поиска ("mysql:mysql", "microsoft:sql_server" ...) задавались не хард кодом, а брались из списка prodList

```
//...
List<string> prodList = new List<string>(); // "mysql:mysql", "microsoft:sql_server" 
//...
List<string> products = new List<string>(); // хранит строки типа "cpe:/o:mysql:mysql:2.4.9", "cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.4.9"
            for (int j = 0; j < products.Count(); j++)
                      if ((!products[j].Contains("mysql:mysql"))
                                      & (!products[j].Contains("microsoft:sql_server"))
                                      & (!products[j].Contains("oracle:mysql"))
                                      & (!products[j].Contains("oracle:database")))
                      {
                             //...
                      }
//...
```

Не понимаю как это можно сделать при том, что у меня используется условие "И".

Делал как-то так:

```
var my = products.Where(x => prodList().Any(p => x.Contains(p)));
```

Comment: Что Вы хотите иметь на выходе - список "продуктов", в названии которых не содержится ни одного элемента из prodList ?

Comment: @isnullxbh да, список

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На коленке как-то так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> patternsList = new List<string>();
            patternsList.AddRange(new string[] 
            { 
                "pt1", "pt2", "pt3" 
            });

            List<string> productsList = new List<string>();
            productsList.AddRange(new string[] 
            { 
                "product01", "prodpt2uct02" 
            });

            var results = productsList.Where( p => !patternsList.Any( m => p.Contains(m) ) );

            foreach (var res in results)
                Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
```

Comment: А если я захочу удалить из productsList список отобранных продуктов, которые в result, то так: 
productsList.Except(result);

Comment: @ViktorBylbas, если это был вопрос - то да )

Comment: @ViktorBylbas, ну и ничего страшного не будет, если Вы реализуете это отсечение в цикле. И еще, совет - не увлекайтесь LINQ. Как мне кажется, а мне так только кажется, ибо большую часть времени я пишу на C++, и только изредка на C# (прошу принять это во внимание), слишком сильно увлекаться LINQ не стоит - некоторые методы "тормозят" выполнение программы. Если есть иное мнение, прошу его предоставить, буду даже рад убедится в обратном !)

Comment: Спасибо. Мне не принципиально обычный цикл или LINQ. Какое решение нашёл, то и использую

Comment: Но, кроме того, хочу изучить всё же LINQ, я их очень поверхностно знаю

Comment: @isnullxbh LiNQ при правильном применении не тормозят, хотя если увлекаться сложными лямбдами и прочими анонимными штуками, то может выстрелить в ногу не хуже указателя, с утечками памяти и прочими трудно вылавливаемыми "прелестями" =)

Comment: @ViktorBylbas изучайте изучайте, только внимательно. При правильном применении LiNQ запросы экономят довольно много строк кода и вашего времени, но это не "волшебная кнопка", поэтому не забудьте заглянуть "под капот" LiNQ, чтобы понимать где оно полезно, а где наоборот.

Comment: @rdorn Спасибо, учту

Comment: @rdorn, сам лично бенчмаркингом не занимался, но представление такое сложилось основываясь на статьях, подобной [этой](https://www.dotnetperls.com/list-contains)

Comment: @isnullxbh Как и любая абстракция, LiNQ тяжелее чем аналогичные алгоритмы более низкого уровня. Но тут уже встает другой вопрос - цель применения, как правило это сокращение времени и сложности поддержки кода. Это просто удобный инструмент для быстрой разработки, как и .NET в целом. Для реально быстрых решений есть СИ, если мало - асм, только заказчику обычно нужно не гениальное или идеальное решение, а дешевое и как можно быстрее, увы. С этой задачей LiNQ справляется отлично не понижая качество кода, а иногда и повышая, за счет исключения из кода кривых велосипедов.

Comment: @ rdorn, спасибо за ответ, я Вас понял)